# Binding in MvvmCross test application for Android does not work (TargetInvocationException)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to make my way through the Xamarin Studio MvvmCross example for Android.
I have uploaded my version of the solution here: https://github.com/Krumelur/MvvmCrossTest

My environment is XS 4.0.13, X.iOS 7.0.2.7, X.Android 4.8.3. All Indie Edition.

I tried the version from Stuart's blog post but I cannot build it because it requires the Xamarin Business Licence because of a reference to System.ServiceModel, so I cannot compare if it would work there.

When running the app I get the exceptions below every time I enter a character into the text field:

```
[0:] MvxBind:Error:132.38 SetValue failed with exception - TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
      at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] index, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, System.Object[] index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Leaf.MvxLeafPropertyInfoSourceBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00080] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Bindings\Source\Leaf\MvxLeafPropertyInfoSourceBinding.cs:86 
InnerException was TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' from assembly 'AndroidDemo.Core'.
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Leaf.MvxLeafPropertyInfoSourceBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00080] in c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding\Bindings\Source\Leaf\MvxLeafPropertyInfoSourceBinding.cs:86 
InnerException was TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' from assembly 'AndroidDemo.Core'.
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` when having the Core project as a PCL and has been reported [on Xamarin's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13081).

You can follow the instructions there and make your own facade assembly or alternatively, in your `ViewModel` change the `RaisePropertyChanged` from:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Foo);
```

to:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("Foo");
```

Comment: You can make all those changes to your properties only to have the Linq exception pop up somewhere else - internal mvvmcross ViewModel matching for example. I would just wait until they fix it or, as you say, replace the façade assembly with the fixed one after every time you install a new version of mono.droid.

Answer (score 0):

Your test project worked first time here

[image: Screenshot]

My details:

```
Xamarin Studio
Version 4.0.12 (build 3)
Installation UUID: 683340a3-6ed3-4d10-ba59-9fc326c5ff7c
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.3 ((no/8d3b4b7)
    GTK 2.24.20
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 302030000

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 5.0 (3332.25)
Build 5A1413

Xamarin.Mac
Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed

Xamarin.Android
Version: 4.8.1 (Business Edition)
Android SDK: /Users/stuartlodge/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86
    Supported Android versions:
        1.6   (API level 4)
        2.1   (API level 7)
        2.2   (API level 8)
        2.3   (API level 10)
        3.1   (API level 12)
        4.0   (API level 14)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.2   (API level 17)
Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 7.0.1.4 (Business Edition)
Hash: 4cfca2f
Branch: 
Build date: 2013-20-09 23:14:32-0400

Build Information
Release ID: 400120003
Git revision: 593d7acb1cb78ceeeb482d5133cf1fe514467e39
Build date: 2013-08-07 20:30:53+0000
Xamarin addins: 25a0858b281923e666b09259ad4746b774e0a873

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.8.5
Darwin Stuarts-MacBook-Air.local 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0
    Mon Jul 29 16:33:49 PDT 2013
    root:xnu-2050.48.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Given that Xamarin have previously had issues with `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`, perhaps this is something that has broken between Xamarin.Android 4.8.1 and 4.8.3?

... so I updated ...

and yes, I see the same problems you see on 4.8.3

So it would seem Xamarin have shipped more PCL updates to stable without testing them against known issues :(

To workaround this:

- you can roll back to 4.8.1
- you can use `RaisePropertyChanged("Foo")` instead of `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Foo)`

Comment: Wrt to the property change raising in general: do you know the CallerMemberNameAttribute? Check this out: https://gist.github.com/Krumelur/7042686

Comment: The reason we don't use that today is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463845/searching-for-the-best-pcl-profile-for-cross-platform-development - but the change away from wp7 is coming soon - likely to happen after firm pcl news from vs13 and xamarin